# Oracle SQL select 'No more data to read from socket'

Tags: oracle, sockets

We are seemingly getting this error trying to run a Oracle SQL SELECT with longish where clause - get the  'No more data to read from socket' from a java application and SQL Developer. Oddly works in one environment and not in another. Database version are the same across the environments;

Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.3.0 - Production "CORE   11.2.0.3.0  Production" TNS for IBM/AIX RISC System/6000: Version
11.2.0.3.0 - Production NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production

The query;

```
SELECT ACCOUNT_DISPLAY_NAME FROM testtable WHERE (((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((certifier = 325036) AND 
(state IN (1, 2))) AND ((decision NOT IN (3, 6, 7)) OR (decision IS NULL))) AND (USR_KEY <> 1)) AND (USR_KEY <> 1)) 
AND (USR_KEY <> 1)) AND (USR_KEY <> 1)) AND (USR_KEY <> 1)) AND (USR_KEY <> 1)) ..... repeat 900 times... ) AND (USR_KEY <> 1)) AND (USR_KEY <> 1)) AND (USR_KEY <> 1)) GROUP BY ACCOUNT_DISPLAY_NAME;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What kind of garbage code is generating this ridiculously redundant query?!

Comment: I don't think I've written this many parentheses in SQL queries in my entire lifetime, let alone in one query.

Comment: its a test query to the show the problem

Comment: SELECT ACCOUNT_DISPLAY_NAME, count(ID) FROM testtable WHERE 
CERTIFIER = 325036
AND STATE IN (1, 2)
AND (DECISION NOT IN (3, 6, 7) OR DECISION IS NULL)
AND USR_KEY <> 1
AND USR_KEY <> 2
AND USR_KEY <> 3
...
etc.
etc.
....
AND USR_KEY <> 1500
GROUP BY ACCOUNT_DISPLAY_NAME;

Comment: No wonder there are no brackets left in the shop.

Comment: There may be more information in the alert log.